# Exponential series property: $\alpha (z)=\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-zn^{2}\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, closed-form

Good day, please a dude, show that if 
$$\alpha (z)=\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-zn^{2}\pi}$$ 
then $\alpha(z^{-1})=z^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha (z)$ for $\Re(z)>0$.

I thought for properties of $e$, or maybe dividing the sum in 2 parts when $n = 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: This is a very non-trivial properties of the function involved (it goes by name theta functions) and believe it or not it is not possible to even guess this property by any manipulation of the series. The simplest and self-contained proof is via Poisson Summation Formula. There are other proofs available from the theory of theta functions.

Comment: this might help http://youtu.be/-GQFljOVZ7I

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may apply the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)

> $$
> \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f\left(n\right)
> $$

with $f(u)=e^{-z\pi u^2}$, observing that $f$ is continuous and satisfies $|f(u)|\le\frac C{\left(1+|u|\right)^2}$ as $u \to \pm \infty$ and observing that, by the use of the [gaussian result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral),
$$
\hat f\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itu}f(u)\:du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-itu}e^{-z\pi u^2}\:du=\frac{e^{\large -\frac{t^2}{4\pi z}}}{\sqrt{z}},\quad \Re z>0.
$$